# Search results replace & with &amp;

Tags: search

When, for example, I search for *Eat & Drink*, the search results show `&amp;` instead of `&`.

> [image: screenshot]

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Used the below code and everything works fine.

```
filter_var($snippet, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```